# Detect mouse click on text selection but ignore when selecting text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to detect mouse click or mouse up event on text selection but actually skip when selecting text?

https://jsfiddle.net/chille1987/ctm4rd7n/

```
<div id="editor">
    <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?</p>

    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>

</div>

<div id="status"></div>
```

And here is my js code

```
$(function() {
    $('#editor').on('mouseup', function(e) {
        let selection = window.getSelection().toString().length;
        let targetContainsSelection = e.target.contains(window.getSelection().baseNode);

        if(selection > 0 && targetContainsSelection) {
            $('#status').text('true');
        } else {
            $('#status').text('false');
        }
    });
})
```

Disired solution is to status text to be true only when i click on selected text but not when I'm selecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a `mousedown` listener and keep track if when the action was started (click or selection) there was a selection. Here is an example:

```js
$(function() {
  let hasSelection = false;
  $('#editor').on('mousedown', function() {
    hasSelection = document.getSelection().toString().length;
  }).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    if (hasSelection) {
      let selection = window.getSelection().toString().length;
      let targetContainsSelection = window.getSelection().containsNode(e.target, true);

      if (selection > 0 && targetContainsSelection) {
        $('#status').text('TRUE').css('color', 'green');
      }
    } else {
      $('#status').text('FALSE').css('color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#status {
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="status">FALSE</div>
<div id="editor">
  <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?</p>

  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>

</div>
```

I've changed `e.target.contains(window.getSelection().baseNode);` to `window.getSelection().containsNode(e.target, true);` because `e.target.contains(window.getSelection().baseNode);` seems to always be `false` in FireFox.

Comment: This does not really do what OP is asking for... Or anything really...

Comment: @ikiK What makes you say that. As I understand it, the OP is looking to have the `#status` element's text set to `true` if a `mouseup` event happens on an element that is part of the text selection. I've tested my solution and it seems to do just that but maybe I've missed something.

Comment: Oh you are right, but it dos not work in Firefox (on two macOS machines, same last version) it stays false. Just tested in Safari and it does work as intended, my apologies. But it is bit confusing, I don't see reason why it wouldn't work in Firefox, and I lost 2 hours trying to solve it myself, maybe even did, it just didn't work in my browser :(. Anyway, your solution is shorter then my attempts and effective.

Comment: @ikiK I've didn't test it in FireFox, I've did that now and it seems that the problems is `e.target.contains(window.getSelection().baseNode);` is always `false`. I've edited my answer to address that.

Comment: @ikiK Thinking about it, this isn't that good of a solution, it is possible to select text in other ways than using the mouse.

Comment: Yeah, `baseNode` not listed at MDN at all anymore. And as far as clicking, that was the request feature ;)